# how to get the size of .apk files in java?

Tags: java, size, apk

can any one help me to find the size of .apk files in java code.
I tried with fileName.length(). But it is not giving the size properly.

Comment: did you open your file as a binary or text?

Answer (score 0):

Like any other file the size of an APK file can be get by:

```
File f = new File(filename);
long fileSize = f.length()
System.out.println(fileSize + " bytes");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java 7 (you should) then this will give you file size:

```
File file = new File("<filename>");
long size = Files.size(file.toPath());
```